# Gensim error with .most_similar(), jupyter kernel restarting

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I cannot get the .most_similar() function to work. I have tried both Gensim 3.8.3 version and now am on the beta version 4.0 . I am working right off of the Word2Vec Model tutorial on each documentation version.

The code giving me error and restarting my kernel:

```
print(wv.most_similar(positive=['car', 'minivan'], topn=5))
```

The above code is verbatim in both 3.8.3 documentation and 4.0. Following tutorials verbatim.

As stated in other stack overflow answers I have tried model.wv.most_similar()

I don't think .most_similar() is depreciated.

Additionally the .doesnt_match() function is not working.

EDIT in regards to gojomo:

Right now I am on Genism 3.8.3. I am using the GloVe Model and Word2Vec models, actually just tried it and it worked with the GloVe model, maybe the Word2Vec model is having a memory problem like gojomo suggested my code below:

I am using linx laptop, I-7 core 1065 cpu, memory 7.4 GiB, 64 bit ubuntu

```
%matplotlib inline

import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

import gensim.downloader as api
wv = api.load('word2vec-google-news-300')

for i, word in enumerate(wv.vocab):
    if i == 10:
        break
    print(word)

pairs = [
    ('programming', 'linux'),   
    ('programming', 'bicycle'), 
    ('programming', 'apple'),  
    ('programming', 'cereal'),    
    ('programming', 'capitalism'),
    ('programming', 'computers'), 
    ('programming', 'python'),  
    ('programming', 'algebra'),  
    ('programming', 'logic'),    
    ('programming', 'math'),
]
for w1, w2 in pairs:
    print('%r\t%r\t%.2f' % (w1, w2, wv.similarity(w1, w2)))

print(wv.most_similar(positive=['math'], topn=5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Jupyter kernel is dying without a clear error message, you are likely running out of memory.

There may be more information logged to the console where you started the Jupyter server. If you expand you question to include any info there, as well as details about the model you've loaded (size on disk) and system you're running on (especially, RAM available), it may be possible to make other suggestions.

Also:

Whereas `gensim-3.8.3` requires a big new increment of RAM when the first `.most_similar()` call is made, the `gensim-4.0.0beta` pre-release only needs a much-smaller increment at that time - so it is far more likely that if a model succeeds in loading, you should also be able to get `.most_similar()` results. So it would also be useful to know:

- How did you install the `gensim-4.0.0beta`, and did you confirm that's the version actually used by your notebook kernel's environment?
- Are you certain that the prior steps (such as loading) have succeeded, and that it's only &  exactly the `most_similar()` that's triggering the failure? (Is it in a separate cell, and before attempting the `most_similar()` can you query other aspects of the model, such as its length or whether it contains certain words, successfully?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I upvoted it and added more of my code. Actually is working on the pretrained GloVe Model but not Word2Vec

Comment: 7.4GB is a bit tight for working with the full `GoogleNews` vector set, which is almost 4GB on disk, and in `gensim-3.8` will expand to at least somewhere over 6GB when you start doing `most_simlar()`-like operations. (If you truly install & use `gensim-4.0.0beta`, it will use a few gigs less data.)

Comment: Also, I'd suggest loading the raw data as a file somewhere you can see & work with it, rather than using the somewhat-opaque `api.load()` functionality. When you have the `GoogleNews` file yourself, you can see its size, and will have the option of using `model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename, limit=1000000)` to just load the 1st 1 million vectors (or whatever smaller-subset you prefer) to save memory.

Comment: Thank you @gojomo I appreciate your insight